# Deserializing XML File using XmlSerializer.Deserialize from MemoryStream not working

Tags: c#, memorystream, xml-deserialization

I'm having trouble deserializing my XML file from a MemoryStream. I have a generated MyXmlFile class and a MemoryStream containing an XML file which I want to deserialize into an object of type MyXmlFile.

```
public static class XmlSerializeObject
{
    public static T FromStream<T>(Stream s)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        return (T) serializer.Deserialize(s);
    }
}
```

I have a MemoryStream ms which contains an xml file. If I try to deserialize that stream into an object of type MyXmlFile I get an exception "There is an error in XML document (0,0)"

```
MyXmlFile test = XmlSerializeObject.FromStream<MyXmlFile>(ms);
```

However I verified that my MemoryStream is correct. If I first write my stream into a file on my disc and than read that file again it works fine.

```
        FileStream outStream = File.OpenWrite("D:\\p.xml");
        outStream.Write(((MemoryStream)ms).ToArray(), 0, ((MemoryStream)ms).ToArray().Length);
        outStream.Flush();
        outStream.Close();
        MyXmlFile test= XmlSerializeObject.FromStream<MyXmlFile>(File.OpenRead("D:\\p.xml"));
```

I was not able to find a solution myself that is why I decided to post my question. Maybe someone had the same problem before and is able to help me out.

Thanks in advance. If anything is unclear please ask.

Comment: Can you please add your definition of the class `MyXmlFile`?

Comment: Can you post how you are loading your XML file into the memory stream and confirm that you are resetting the stream back to position 0 with something like 'Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)'

Comment: It sounds like you might have used the memorystream prior to passing it to the serializer, could that be the case?  If so, reset the memory streams position beforehand. - EDIT: @Kane beat me to it on the stream.Position thing ^^

Comment: And @AllenG beat us both

Comment: Only because I've done exactly the same thing too many times.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you instantiated your memory stream prior to your call to deserialize (say, to load the XML into the memory stream in the first place) it may be that it's at the wrong index.  Try

```
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
```

To go back to the beginning of the stream.

Comment: I feel stupid for not thinking of that and trying it but that's totally why it didn't work. :/ Thank you very much

Comment: It's happened to me more than I care to admit.

Answer (score 0):

You must set position of MemoryStream to the 0.

```
((MemoryStream)ms).Position = 0;
MyXmlFile test = XmlSerializeObject.FromStream<MyXmlFile>(ms);
```